# How to connect to an Azure SQL Server using the PrivateLink IP

Tags: azure, networking, azure-sql-server, azure-private-link

I have an Azure logical SQL server to which I added a Private Link, the NIC is attached to an existing vnet\subnet. Our company's VPN is linked to that vnet and I can see other devices on the private link's subnet but not the SQL Server.

The SQL Server is reachable on the public URL (temporarily for testing) but trying to ping or tracert the server with the private IP fails, I can ping and tracert to other VMs on the same subnet.

I'm not using a custom DNS zone because it's imperative that we configure it with the IP and I haven't made any changes to our company DNS (I'm expecting not to have to).

Other than creating the private link and attaching it to the SQL Server, **what else needs to be done? What am I missing?**

Comment: Could you please add the error you are getting,  Azure SQL DB gateway use the name to route correctly your connection to the SQL host. We must use the FQDN to connect to Azure SQL .

Answer (score 1):

I'am working on the same Issue. It's still not solved yet but there are some steps you need to do.

For the Connectivity it's required to add a DNS, especially if you want to connect from the On-Prem. Azure has a default DNS-Solution for Azure-Resources. The Problem is: From On-Prem you can't access the default Azure-DNS-Service.
So you have to configure a DNS-Zone (in Azure or On-Prem).